# I get undefined error using pure javascript in my code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a material ripple effect to an element using pure javascript using the code below. The problem is that the effect works only for the first click.
If I try to click the button again, I get the message `Uncaught TypeError: circle is undefined` on my console.

```js
function createRipple(event) {
  const target = event.currentTarget;
  const circle = target.classList.add("ripple");

  const ripple = circle.getElementsByClassName("ripple")[0];

  if (ripple) {
    ripple.remove();
  }

}


const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("my-ripple");
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", createRipple);
}
```

```css
.my-ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  font-family: sans;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.ripple::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: ripple 600ms linear;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-ripple">Click me</div>
```

Comment: `target.classList.add("ripple");` returns `undefined`. You seem to expect it to be `target` or something else. I'm not even sure what.

Comment: What I try to do is to add class "ripple" on any clicked element that contain already the class "my-ripple".

Comment: console target, I think it is null or undefined.

Comment: try `document.getElementsByClassName("ripple");`, not `circle`

Comment: @RitikBanger no, it's not.

Comment: var target = document.getElementByClassName("my-ripple");
target.classList.add("ripple");

Comment: @RitikBanger this code is not correct for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classList` does not return an object. And you do not need it actually, because you already have the `target` instance, so fetching it again by class is not necessary. Instead just remove the class from it directly with a timeout:

```
function createRipple(event) {
  const target = event.currentTarget;
  target.classList.add("ripple");
  setTimeout(function() {
    target.classList.remove("ripple");
  }, 600);
}
```